# Black Part on Baked Images as Planes

Tags: texture-baking, baking

i'm trying to bake a plane with a .png image texture on it. But after baking, there's this black part on the baked image texture where the transparent side is. Is there any solution regarding to this problem? Please see screenshots below;
[image: Output Picture]
[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Probably you can change the transparent node in the material by something giving a solid color where the alpha is (diffuse, for instance).

Comment: Or you can try to start with a texture that is transparent and uncheck 'clear image' in the bake panel.